# WSO2 EI with RabbitMQ - how to reject a message?

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2

Using WSO2EI 6.4.0 with RabbitMQ as inbound transport as described in the documentation [RabbitMQ AMQP Transport](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/RabbitMQ+AMQP+Transport).

Seems working well, though there's only the "sunny day" scenario covered.

Requiring preserving the message ordering, on exception we cannot just requeue the message back to the queue.  If the backend service is not available, I'd like to rollback the message and attempt to process the message later. As far I understood we need to send the *nack* response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="test_mgs_processing_proxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,rabbitmq,local">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="step" value="test_mgs_processing_proxy"/>
         </log>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
         <!-- simulate an exception has occured -->
         <property name="SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY" scope="axis2" value="true"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <step xmlns="">test_mgs_processing_proxy</step>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">amq.topic</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">app_a</parameter>
   <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Setting `FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED` makes the message considered as consumed. Even if we set the `SET_ROLLBACK_ONLY` property, the message stays in the NACK state and is not resent (at least no quickly).

Question - using the RabbitMQ AMQP Transport, is there a way to configure redelivery interval of not-processed messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it is an issue in WSO2 EI 6.4.0. https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/issues/4739

The issue is not there when you use Inbound Endpoints. The issue is there only when you use a Proxy with rabbitmq transport.